# SQL multiple reference

Tags: sql

I’m in a dilemma choosing the best strategy to model my database.

Let’s say I have a two tables: `Variable(ID)` and `Object(ID)`.

Now, an entry in Variable may reference another entry in Variable or in Object.

To model this, one approach is creating 2 mapping tables:

```
Variable_Variable(variable_id, variable_id), Variable_Object(variable_id, object_id)
```

The other approach is to have in the Variable table two reference columns:
`Variable(ID, parent_variable_id, parent_object_id)`.
If this variable references another variable, then the parent_object_id is null and vice-versa.

I feel first approach is neater, but second approach is faster when querying the database.

Is there any standard to apply in this cases? Which is the usual approach for these cases?
Thanks,
Danny.

Comment: Are there `1:1`, `1:n` or `n:m` relations?

Comment: If a variable can reference zero or one parent, either another variable or object, I would go with the second approach. Having mapping tables would only be useful to model many-to-many relationships. With your first approach you would have to check to up to 2 tables to find the parent.

Comment: Hi Shnugo. All relations are 1 to 1. One variable can ONLY reference another variable OR a single object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that all relations are `1:1` I would go with your second approach of having `parent_variable_id` and `parent_object_id` columns in your `Variable` table.

You could then have a `CHECK` constraint to ensure that only one or the other column contains a value (or neither, if your variables don't have to reference a parent).

Another alternative that you didn't mention is using a single mapping table `MappingTable (variable_id, parent_variable_id, parent_object_id)`. The downside with this is that, if variables must have a parent, you will then have to enforce a 1:1 relationship between the `Variables` table and `Mappings` table.

I would only consider using a mapping table if modelling an `n:n` relationship, or if there is additional information about the relationship between a variable and it's parent that needs to be recorded.